# What is a good Python template engine to resolve paths?

Tags: python, path, conventions

I'm looking for an up to date python template engine to resolve paths

I'm dealing with a lot of paths to resolve at my job. We are currently using the [Shotgun Software tank module](https://sg-shotgunsoftware.s3.amazonaws.com/tank/docs/core/v0.12.6_0121_021710/Tank-API-Reference.html) but want to get rid of it. We have template paths with keys as shown below and provide the template engine with a dictionnary with keys matching the ones in the template. I've already found info about Jinja, Django template engine, wheezy (that seems to be the closest to what we wanna achieve).

What we have right now (simplified):

templates.yml

```
project_root_path : 'C:/data/{project_name}'
resources_path : '@project_root_path/{date}/Resources'
```

main.py

```py
template_engine = TemplateEngine('templates.yml')
d = {'project_name':"Test", 'date':"20192603"}
print(template_engine.get("resources_path", d))
> C:/data/Test/20192603/Resources
```

What we would like to have :

main.py

```py
# getting an entity item from our DB using sqlalchemy
item = datasource.items.one(id=0)
template_engine = TemplateEngine('templates.yml')
print(template_engine.get("resources_path",
                           project_name=item.project.name,
                           date=item.date))
```

Is there a Python module that gets close to this ?

Comment: This may not be the answer your looking for, but you can use os.path.abspath() to pull the entire path of a file.  Also you can use os.path.basename() to pull the base directory/file name alone.                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Also your 'yml' file seems its in the format of a dictionary already.  Could you therefore just read it into a dictionary and get the values that way?